# Changes action on PHP contact form

Tags: php, contacts

Changed action on PHP Contact form from old.php to new.php, yet when i submit the form, i get an error which states cannot find old.php.

Could this be a problem with resetting cookies/router?

Code as requested: (first line of form)

```
<form name="contactform" form id="contactform" method="post" action="old.php" onSubmit="return validate.check(this)">
```

Changed to:

```
    <form name="contactform" form id="contactform" method="post" action="/loc1/new.php" onSubmit="return validate.check(this)">
```

I have deleted old.php from the parent directory.

Comment: forgot to add, i deleted old.php

Comment: we need your code to be able to help you. thb it could be a cookie problem but I doubt your code is so "complex" that it depends on a cookie which files are included...

Comment: Could be a cache problem. Clear out your cache and see if that works.

Comment: Well just take a look what action is shown in the form you submit. CTRL-U or View>Page Source to look at the html markup and check the action inside the form tag.

Answer (score 0):

Please double check javascript code you are calling on submit (`validate.check(this)`) may be there is some code which is changing action of your form.